# Having trouble with data validation in Php for a online store

Tags: php

I have to create a website for a school project and I am making a guitar shop.  The problem is I have having trouble with data validation when a user selects the amount they want to buy.  My current code is

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
 <h1>Welcome to the Acoustic Guitar Shop!</h1>
</head>
<body>
<form action = '<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>' method = 'post'>

    <?php

$Guitar1=array('Item'=>1,
'Guitar Type'=>"Fender FA-100 <img src=FenderFA100.jpg width='128' 
 height='128'>",
'Price'=>150);
$Guitar2=array('Item'=>2,
'Guitar Type'=>"Yamaha FG800 <img src=Yamaha800.jpg width='128' 
 height='128'>",
'Price'=>200);    
$Guitar3=array('Item'=>3,
'Guitar Type'=>"Yamaha FG830 <img src=Yamaha830.jpg width='128' 
 height='128'>",
'Price'=>299.99);
$Guitar4=array('Item'=>4,
'Guitar Type'=>"Big Baby Taylor <img src=Taylor.jpg width='128' 
 height='128'>",
'Price'=>399.99);
$Guitar5=array('Item'=>5,
'Guitar Type'=>"Martin DX1KAE <img src=MartinDX1AE.jpg width='128' 
 height='128'>",
'Price'=>599.00);
// Setting Up the Multi Dimentional Array

$Guitars=array($Guitar1, $Guitar2, $Guitar3, $Guitar4, $Guitar5);

// Creating a array for all Guitars.
echo "<center>";
echo "<table border='3' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5'>";
echo '<th>Item</th><th>Guitar Type</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th>';
//Creating borders and heading for table.

  for($i=0; $i<count($Guitars); $i++)

  {  
   $qty = "quantity" . $i;
  }

  foreach($Guitars as $i=>$Value)
  {

   echo "<tr><td>{$Guitars[$i] ['Item']}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$Guitars[$i] ['Guitar Type']}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$Guitars[$i] ['Price']}</td>";
   echo '<td><input type="text" name='. $qty .'></tr>';
  }
//Creating a for loop to display the table.  
//Created html forms to allow the user to choice the amount of guitars they 
wish to purchase.              

if(array_key_exists('submit_button' , $_POST))
// IF statement that tells the program to display a html table if the user 
presses submit
{
If(is_numeric("$qty"))   
{$error_found=False;
  echo "<table <table border='3' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5'>
       <th>Item</th><th>Guitar Type</th><th>Price</th><th>Extended 
Price</th>";

//The submit_button input was valid, so it would display the invoice.  
}
else
{
$error_found=TRUE;
echo 'Value entered is invalid';
}
//Checking data validation.

}
 //Creating a if statement for the submit_button.
  else {   


       }
?>
<b><center><input type="submit" name = "submit_button" value = "Purchase">
</center></b>


   </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

The main problem I have is with my last if statement, it keeps saying the value is invalid even though it is valid and I am not sure how to properly fix it.
I am new to coding so I am not sure how to fix this.  I need to also display a invoice after using to display the final price of the items the user selected. How would i go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: verify the value of `$qty`

Comment: Is this the if statement you are talking about? `If(is_numeric("$qty"))`

Comment: @Akintunde the value of $qty is supposed to be the names of the forms in my for loop.  I used $qty = "quantity" . $i; in my loop to get the names Quantity0, quantity1, quantity2, etc so I can store the names in the $_POST array.  But I am not sure if I did it correctly.

Comment: i don't understand your syntax. Shouldn't the quantity be 5?? Looks like you are physically hard-coding the array. Why then have a loop?

Comment: @Akintunde oh sorry the quantity should be 5 and the value $qty was suppose to give each form a name from Quantity1-5.  Also, the loop was to display all the information onto a table from the array $Guitars.  One of the requirements for the project is to use a loop to display the arrays on a table.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line `If(is_numeric("$qty"))` to `if(is_numeric($qty))` as you aren't actually comparing the variable you are actually checking the string "$qty".

**EDIT**

If you want to get the form value for the element with the name = $qty you need to use post variables. try `if(is_numeric($_POST[$qty]))` This should get the textbox value with the name "quantity5".

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but for some reason even after I changed it, it still says the number I entered is invalid even though its suppose to be valid.

Comment: In your else statement add `echo '$qty = ' . $qty;` to see what the if statement is actually receiving.

Comment: Its saying $qty=quantity4 Value entered is invalid.

Comment: In your code you only assign $qty a value in the for loop which will always make it a string and never a number as you are concatenating "quantity" each iteration of your loop.

Comment: What exactly is $qty supposed to be here is it supposed to be an input from the form?

Comment: $qty was suppose to be a variable to give each text box a unique name, to make each input quantity as a new variable.  I still need to create an invoice that displays the products that the user has selected and needed a unique name for each text box in my table.  Sorry if my code a bit confusing im not sure if im doing it correctly.

Comment: No problem :-) I have edited my answer now hopefully it should help you

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the validation is if there is only one `qty` variable, but in fact, you have 5, named `quantity1` to `quantity5`. You need a loop to validate each one of them. Remember you can use dynamic variable names in PHP using a syntax like `$_POST[${'quatity'.$index}]` to access the variables in you _POST array.

Comment: Thanks, i was wondering why only my quantity5 was working properly.  But, I was assuming with this if statement                                      
      for($i=0; $i<count($Guitars); $i++)
      
      {  
       $qty = "quantity" . $i;
      } it would work properly, do i need to create a new loop for this variable only?

Comment: In that loop you are creating the _names_ of the variables, in order to obtain its value, you have to wrap them like `${$qty}`. (notice the use of _$_ twice).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer to your question, but rather an alternative to your approach:

You can create input arrays from HTML, if you change your line

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name='. $qty .'></tr>';
```

for either:

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]"></tr>'; // 0 base array
```

or

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity['. $qty .']"></tr>'; // use your index (start at 1)
```

Then you will have ONE variable named quantity, which is an array with the values you were expecting, no more mangling with variable names for validation.

If you are open to using HTML5, I would suggest changing the input type to "number" and use the other attributes (value, min, max, etc). [Input Number Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_number.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your help, ill try one of these alternatives out.